# Offset Jquery Tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, offset

I'm redesigning/streamlining my site and going with jQuery to do it but some things I did manually I just can't figure out who to do in jQuery.

I got my tabs + according working but I want to off set the first tab so I can put in a logo and then put some text right aligned after the tabs

I'd also like to put a spacer in the middle for an image:

[image]

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-smaller-1">Biography</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-smaller-2">Personality</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-smaller-3">Powers/Abilities</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-smaller-4">Forms</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-smaller-5">Equipment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-smaller-6">Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-smaller-7">Statistics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-smaller-8">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-smaller-1">
    <!-- Accordion -->
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>First</h3>
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        <h3>Second</h3>
        <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
        <h3>Third</h3>
        <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

foudn it on my own so i'm sharing for anyone who want to do similar for the image placement and right text just use absolute position

```
<div id="tabs" class="tabs">
<div style="position: absolute; right: 1em; top: 0em; margin-top: 1em;">
sdfsdfsdf sdfsdf sdf sdfsdf
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 0.5em;">
<img src="../images/TQG_Logo.png" height="35" alt="" border="0" style="margin-left:0.1em;">
</div>
```

For the offset put a Style on the first button

```
<li style="margin-left: 7em"><a href="#tabs-smaller-1">Biography</a></li>
```